# Variance of $X-Y$ cannot be negative

Tags: statistics, covariance

Suppose we have 2 non independent variable X and Y.

Since $$Var(X-Y)= Var(X) + Var (Y) -2Cov(X,Y)$$

Would it be possible for the above to be negative in the case when $$Var(X) + Var(Y) < 2 Cov(X,Y)$$?

Comment: $\text{Var}(X-Y)\geq 0$, from definition, so it can't be negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the fact that a variance is non-negative, i.e.
$$var(X - Y) \geq 0$$
So
$$var(X) + var(Y) - 2cov(X,Y) \geq 0$$
Hence
$$var(X) + var(Y)  \geq 2cov(X,Y) $$

Comment: It's more elementary than you think. $\text{Var}X = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2] \geq 0$, in particular, $\text{Var}(X-Y)\geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}$No. You have
$$
\v(X) + \v(Y) - 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = \v(X-Y) \ge 0
$$
and therefore
$$
\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) \le \frac {\v(X) + \v(Y)} 2.
$$
If the sum of the variances is less than $2,$ then the covariance is less than $1.$